# Perplexing SQL statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, logic

Given a table with this data:

```
   L    |    N
-------------------
   A    |    1
   A    |    3
   A    |    5
   B    |    5
   B    |    7
   B    |    9
   C    |    1
   C    |    2
   C    |    3
```

Write an elegant SQL query that achieves this:

FIND Letters (L) that include ALL of 1, 2, and 3

The expected outcome is obvious:
A single row with "C"

Anyone have solution?  And no, this isn't a CS homework question. Just curious how you would write a SQL query to find the solution.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select L
from MyTable
where N in (1,2,3)
group by L
having count(distinct N) = 3
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31920/2)

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can also
Messier but typically faster
Would only go this route of L was big, like over 100,000, and you were having performance problems.

```
select     L from mytable where N = 1
 intersect
select     L from mytable where N = 2
 intersect
select     L from mytable where N = 3
```